# Add Child block to particular widget

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, layout, custom-block

For my project i do want to add child block to particular widget. Widget is being added via CMS Page. i want to add child block to that widget.

Is it possible ? Magento 1 or Magento 2 any answer acceptable. I just want the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably by creating the block within your widget template. e.g

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourblock')->toHtml();
```

You can create a paramater in your widget to create a toggle to include this block or not within the template. e.g

```
if (showExtraBlock) :
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourblock')->toHtml();
endif;
```

This will work in Magento 1 and 2